# Razor pages have stopped working by default since swapping from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, razor-pages

I have an application which was previously running on the .NET framework that I'm swapping over to .NET Core. Since moving to .NET Core, it looks like the functionality of Razor pages has changed.

This code which previously worked:

Controller:

```
public class Template
{
    public string PrimaryColour = "rgb(0, 21, 77)";
}

public class MyControllerController : ParentController
{
    private readonly ICompositeViewEngine _viewEngine;

    public MyControllerController (ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine)
    {
        _viewEngine = viewEngine;
    }

    private String GetViewAsString()
    {
        ViewData.Model = new Template();
        var viewEngineResult = _viewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext, "Home", true);
        
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                ControllerContext,
                viewEngineResult.View,
                ViewData,
                TempData,
                sw,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );

            await viewEngineResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
}
```

`Home.cshtml` view:

```
@model Template

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans' rel='stylesheet' />
    
    @await Html.InlineStyle("document-colours")
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

`document-colours.css`:

```
:root {
    --key-primary: @Model.PrimaryColour;
}
```

When running on the .NET Framework,  `MyControllerController.GetViewAsString` would return this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans' rel='stylesheet' />
    
    <style>
    :root {
        --key-primary: rgb(0, 21, 77);
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

However running on .NET Core, it now returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans' rel='stylesheet' />
    
    <style>
    :root {
        --key-primary: @Model.PrimaryColour;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Do I need to do something to instruct it to recurse into linked documents?

Comment: Hello @Andy, did you able to resolve the issue? Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an application which was previously running on the .NET
> framework that I'm swapping over to .NET Core. Since moving to .NET
> Core, it looks like the functionality of Razor pages has changed.

Based on my test, it seems that,  its your `Html.InlineStyle("document-colours")` self defined tag helper which causing the problem as not sure what's the code base or logic behind.

However, as per .netcore architecture, as you are using strongly type reference which is `@model Template` you can call its property directly as following:

```
 <style>
      :root{
            --key-primary: @Model.PrimaryColour;
      }
  </style>
```

In addition to this, your project reference need to modified as following:

```
@model ProjectName.Models.Template
```

Full Code Snippet:

In my test I have implemented as following:

```
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.Template

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans' rel='stylesheet' />
  <style>
      :root{
            --key-primary: @Model.PrimaryColour;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="color:@Model.PrimaryColour">Test CSS</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** Rest of your code I kept as it is. Nothing need to be changed.

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** As you can see, I am getting the expected result which you are looking for. Thus, make sure your self defined tag helper logic `@await Html.InlineStyle("document-colours")`

**Alternative Test Finding:**

Furthermore, I have also test in following way, using [@Html.Raw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper.raw?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which also working as expected:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            var renderView = GetViewAsString();

            ViewBag.Content = renderView;
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">
        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Content)
    </h1>

</div>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I thought Html.InlineStyle("document-colours") was an inbuilt function, it turns out that it's an extension that just returns the contents of a file in a <style> block.  My assumption now is that in asp.net this worked because the engine did multiple passes of the page to make sure all code was executed, but I'm guessing asp.net core doesn't do this?  If not I think I'm going to have to go and update all of my similar methods so that they render the string they are returning.

Comment: Thanks for your response Andy, yeah right you are, I think you would need to modify your custom tag Html.InlineStyle or you could use the way I did. But the reason for repercussion is `Html.InlineStyle` which I mostly focused on to point you exactly. Thanks once again.